# Chrome extension if else statement does not execute the else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-chrome-extension

So, I have the following code for an extension that cycles through open tabs with a specific URL.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
console.log('Get URL');
chrome.tabs.query(
    {currentWindow: true, url: 'https://www.google.com/*'},
    function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
      console.log('Tab ID, URL: ', tab.id, ' ', tab.url);
          if(tab.url !== '')
          {
            //tab.focus();
            console.log('if !== \'\'');
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "YES"});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "GREEN"})
            var updateProperties = {"active": true};
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, updateProperties, function(tab){ });
          }
          else
          {
            chrome.windows.create({ url: "https://www.google.com", type: "popup" });
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "NO"});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color: "RED"})
          }
    });
});
```

If the array has items, then the if condition is true, and the instructons for if are executed.
If the array has no items, then the if condition is false and nothing is executed. My understanding is, that the set of instructions in else should be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tabs.forEach calls the function passed to it for each of the elements in the array. if the array contains 0 elements, the function will not be called and thus it will not reach to the point where if condition is checked.

your else case will only get executed when tabs contain one or more elements and at least one of those elements has tab.url set to "" or ''.

Comment: That's exactly it.